# Which method gets called the moment the activity is fully laid out and ready for user interaction?

Tags: android, android-activity

I need a way to run some code at the exact moment in which the activity is fully loaded, laid out, drawn and ready for the user's touch controls. Which method/listener does that?

Comment: It might help if you actually bothered to explain what you think you plan to do "at the exact moment". After all, you assume there is such an "exact moment" (there's not, really) and you assume to the extent that there is such a moment that you can get control to "run some code".

Comment: I don't think it is relevant to the matter at hand, which is - which method is called at that moment or some short time after it. Anyway, I'm planning to call a method that loads textures which i've found doesn't work correctly unless called after everything is layed out and visible

Comment: @CommonsWare: On iOS, there is such a moment, it is `viewDidAppear`. Rarely needed, but I've used it occasionally. There doesn't seem to be an equivalent callback in Android. MAYBE overriding top-level view's `onDraw`, call base.onDraw, then do the custom code. Would also need to run the code after testing a flag set in `onResume`, and cleared after that code runs - so that it only runs once per `onResume`. Do you think that would be roughly the same moment as iOS `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: I am not an iOS developer and so I do not know the semantics of `viewDidAppear`. There's nothing stopping you from doing what you are proposing, but my guess is that there is a better solution for whatever problem you are trying to solve with a `viewDidAppear` equivalent.

Answer (score 28):

Commonsware is right, without explaining what your are trying to do and why, it's not possible to answer your question and I suspect, with detail, you are probably thinking about it the wrong way.

However, I do have some code where I needed to do some very funky layout stuff after everything had been measured.

I could have extended each of the view classes in the layout and overriden `onMeasure()` but that would have been a lot of work.  So, I ended up doing this.  Not great, but it works.

mainMenuLayout is the layout I needed to get funky with.  The `onGlobalLayout` callback is called when the layout has completed drawing.  `Utils.setTitleText()` is where the funkiness takes place and as I pass mainMenuLayout to it, it has access to the position and size of all of the child views.

```
mainMenuLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {

                    // only want to do this once
                    mainMenuLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

                    // set the menu title, the empty string check prevents sub-classes
                    // from blanking out the title - which they shouldn't but belt and braces!
                    if (!titleText.equals("")){
                        Utils.setTitleText(_context,mainMenuLayout,titleText);
                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: beautiful answer, less the first paragraph. Why this attitude ? the guy has clearly revealed all the required input. Anyway, in my case of a header view added to a ListView, the ViewTreeObserver listeners did not do the trick. It has worked though by subclassing View and overriding its onLayout() method as described. Funny thing the method got called twice, with the first call actually not having the header view layed out.

Comment: I think this code will run after *layout*, but before *drawing*, which is different than was asked.

Answer (score 17):

I've found that if I post a `Runnable` to the message queue, it will run after the content for the activity has been drawn. For example, if I want the width and height of a `View`, I would do this:

```
view.post( new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        int width = view.getWidth(); // will be non-zero
        int height = view.getHeight(); // will be non-zero
    }
} );
```

I've found success with this anytime after I call `setContentView()`.

Comment: @JasonRobinson: I think Simon's answer runs after *layout*, but before *drawing*. That's different than OP asked.

Comment: @JBlaz it works and makes logical sense if you understand how the UI message queue works, but it is more of a workaround. Simon's answer is probably the cleanest approach.

Comment: Just make sure you don't use Simon's answer in fragment

Answer (score 0):

**onRestoreInstanceState** method is the one called to restore UI state which is called after **onResume** .I think you can use this onRestoreInstanceState method.. and put your code after restoring UI state from the savedInstanceState...

Comment: Not true now (and maybe never was...). When an activity is first created, `onRestoreInstanceState` is **not** called. There is nothing to restore, so no reason for OS to call it. I believe (though am not certain) it also **won't be called** (even when returning from background) unless you previously did `onSaveInstanceState` while app was going into background. [Tested just now, on emulator running Android API 23.]

Answer (score -1):

Try `onPostResume()` called after `onResume()` at this moment the Activity instance should be visible and all underlying Views are rendered. In many situations this is true when `onResume()` is called as well.

Comment: The same. In fact, it's not recommended to use it: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPostResume()

Comment: I would not say it is not recommended, what they say is "Applications will generally not implement this method" as it is intended for other purposes

Comment: I'm fairly certain your last sentence is wrong - `onResume` is called before any view's `onDraw`. Your first sentence is also wrong, at least when displaying a `fragment`. [I have not tested when no fragment.] This can be demonstrated by creating a fragment with a custom view as its top-level view, and putting a break on view's `onDraw`. With fragments, the only difference between the activity's `onResume` and `onPostResume`, is that the fragment's `onResume` runs during `onPostResume`, so code you put *after* `base.onPostResume();` can rely on the fragment having resumed.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it little helps:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow(){}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer is so downvoted. It worked for me. I needed to show a popup window, but I couldn't do it from onCreate because I kept getting  "Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?"

Comment: @Martin Koubek Great Answer !  This is exactly my problem, needed to show popup window after the main activity window attached to to the window (:

Comment: I used this solution earlyer but I found a problem: the menu did not inflated since onAttachedToWindow() had called. So ie. when I tried to click on a menuitem programmatically in onAttachedToWindow(), the menuitem didn't exists yet.