# requestlayout, invalidate behaviour

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, paint

hat is the correct way to make the changes visible onscreen after having programatically changed the font of some TextView's Paint objects  ?

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    mMainController.grads(mLytHowToPlay, true, FaceTypes.FACEIT, GradTypes.NONE, 8);
    mLytHowToPlay.requestLayout();
        mLytHowToPlay.invalidate();
}
```

The grads() method call above is the one that recursively treats mLytHowToPlay's children and makes changes to their Paint objects. I have also tried this sequence from onCreate() and onStart() with the same effect - changes are not made visible until the Activity gets navigated away from and then navigated back to again.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Simon's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302803/android-which-method-gets-called-the-moment-the-activity-is-fully-layed-out-an) and my comment to it. What I was been looking for was actually a callback triggered just after the layout process completed.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your onCreate() method create a Thread like the one below.

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mMainController.grads(mLytHowToPlay, true, FaceTypes.FACEIT, GradTypes.NONE, 8);
        mLytHowToPlay.requestLayout();
        mLytHowToPlay.invalidate();

    }
},2000);
```

What this will do is wait 2 seconds after the app is created and then run your process. You should be able to play with the timing and lower it or raise it depending on what you need.

Comment: works! although I don't think I 'll accept is as a solution; it is more of a hack. But thanks!

Comment: Well from my understanding, onCreate() (like the load method in .Net) is creating your activity and it's only called once in your activity's life cycle (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). The process you want to do would be done when the activity is Active which android doesn't really have a method to handle. onStart() is called as the application is becoming visible so you'd need to create a handler to fire off after the onCreate or onStart creates/instantiates your activty.

Comment: I wouldn't know, there is one Activity in my app that does well without this delay workaround. It works with that code called from onResume()

Comment: there are 3 activities that need this fix, one that does not. The "entry point" (if by that you mean the first activity to be shown) needs the fix too.